# preg_replace apostrophie for words ending s using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok, so i am matching any word ending in **S** and replacing it with **'S** for a mysql search, and all works fine..

```
$check = "string to tests"; 
if(preg_match("/s\b/", $check)) {
    preg_match("/s\b/", $check, $match);
    $no_apos = $match[0];
    $with_apos = str_replace($no_apos, "&#39;s", $check);
    $converted = "LIKE '%$check%' OR subject LIKE '%$with_apos%'";
}

$search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE subject $converted ORDER BY subject ASC");
$result = preg_replace("#($check|$with_apos)#i", "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>$1</span>", $result);
```

but i get this error when it fetches the result:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '3'
```

all the matching works, it just seems to be the the replace it doesnt like.
any idea why?

EDIT: also is there a better regex for matching any string containing a word ending in S?

Comment: It's because `$with_apos` contains a `#` that it throws an error, try to use an unique delimiter.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV - if that's the reason - dump it as an answer so it can be voted upon.

Comment: @Duniyadnd This should be the reason: see the &#39; in the str_replace call...

Comment: @Duniyadnd half answers shouldn't be posted, the solution provided by bwoebi is the way to go ...

Comment: lolz, @FoxyFish please do some efforts, bwoebi has pointed you to the right direction, use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). Since I'm in a good mood I'll give you the codez: `$check = preg_quote($check, '#');$with_apos = preg_quote($with_apos, '#');$result = preg_replace("#($check|$with_apos)#i", "<span style='background-color:#EEEE00'>$1</span>", $result);`

Comment: thanks, i've never used preg_quote before is all.

Comment: I advise you to consider the case when $check doesn't have any words ending with 's'. Right now it will fail to create the $converted variable hence messing up the query you run.